# cannot connect to mongodb remotely, it refuses connection in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, remote-access

**i thought this question is addressed by other discussions in the forum but all of my tries have so far failed, despite following the instructions very carefully.**

i am trying to setup mongodb to work on the backend of my nodejs server.
i modified the sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf file:

```
# mongod.conf
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
#security:
authorization: enabled
#operationProfiling:
#replication:
replSetName: volatize0
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

followed by:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

then execute:

```
>sudo netstat -tnlp
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name 
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1888/mongod         
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27019         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4895/mongod
```

i still cannot connect to the server via node.js
it refuses the connection.

can you guide me how i can make the mongodb listen to the static ip in addition to the localhost?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1888/mongod
```

This means your bind ip is 127.0.0.1. Either your config file is not where the server expects it, it's in the right place but the server isn't configured to look for it, or it is malformed.

Or, everything is correct but you haven't restarted the server after changing the config file.